# Set RasterStack and SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to same coordinate system in R

Tags: raster, r, rgdal

I have a [shapefile of 8094 Italian municipalities](https://www.istat.it/it/archivio/222527) which I imported into R as a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame using `readOGR`. When I `plot` this, I get the following map:

[image]

I also have a RasterStack of global monthly temperatures.

I want to overlay the rasterstack with the shapefile to extract the values for each municipality. I have done this many times before (with other shapefiles) using the `extract` command in R, i.e., `monthly_temperatures <- raster::extract(tmp_month, Italy_map)`

However, this time it doesn't work because the RasterStack and the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame use different coordinate systems. The `proj4string` of the Italy map is `+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`  and the `bbox` is as follows:

```
    min     max
x  313279.3 1312016
y 3933520.1 5220291
```

Of the RasterStack the `proj4string` is `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs` and the `bbox` is as follows:

```
    min     max
x  -180    180
y   -90     90
```

They clearly do not overlap. Does someone know how to fix this issue? I have looked for different shapefiles of Italian municipalities online but the one from ISTAT is the only one I have found. I am working in RStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know, R doesn't *project on the fly* while processing with multiple layers. All layers should share CRS for any process.

For projecting CRS, use `spTransform`. Always project the vector file over the raster file:

```
Italy_mapWGS84 <- spTransform(Italy_map, CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'))

monthly_temperatures <- raster::extract(tmp_month, Italy_mapWGS84)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you very much!